# Declaring class variables after assigning them values in C++

Tags: c++

Here I have a class called `Shape`

```
class Shape 
{
   public:
      void setWidth(int w)
      {
         width = w;
      }
      void setHeight(int h)
      {
         height = h;
      }
   protected:
      int width;
      int height;
};
```

It compiles just fine, but how is it that I am even allowed to assign `width` and `height` values even though I didn't declare them previously? How does the compiler know at this point what they are?

Comment: This is called "class visibility": declaration order doesn't matter if it's inside class. It's C++ feature.

Comment: @Matt: Declaration order does matter inside a class. E.g. you cannot use a type in member declaration before that type is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the language works *as if* a class with member function definitions inline, is rewritten by the compiler as

```
class Shape 
{
   public:
      void setWidth(int w);
      void setHeight(int h);

   protected:
      int width;
      int height;
};

inline void Shape::setWidth(int w)
{
   width = w;
}

inline void Shape::setHeight(int h)
{
   height = h;
}
```

This has great explanatory power in general, but, heads up: it may not necessarily be so good a model for nested classes.

---

General comments:

- Strive to provide practical interfaces. E.g. if setting the width or height of a shape updates its screen presentation, then if I want to change both, with the current interface that will cause two screen updates.
- Instead of attribute setters, consider functions that either *do* or *inspect*, e.g. in this case, a `resize` function or set of functions.
- `protected` data is generally not a good idea. Make it `public` or `private` by default, unless you have a very good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Within functions you need to declare a variable before using it.

This is not required for class variables. Actually for variables and functions defined directly within a class, the order does not matter at all. Interestingly, this is not the case for types defined inside a class.

Comment: Whether the order matters depends on the usage.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Hmm, don't get it. Could you elaborate (just a little)?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Thanks, got it and edited my answer.

Comment: Well, the order does matter for variables too. :-) E.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68a82e4e47317a12