# Using private nested type as parameter

Tags: c++

I'm getting this strange problem which I don't know why happens. The first and second of the following code snippets compile, while the third does not:

Compiles:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { Bar(); }

private:
    class Bar {};
};
```

Compiles:

```
class Foo {
    class Bar {};  // Or only forward declare here and define later

public:
    Foo(Bar) {}
}
```

Does not compile:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(Bar) {}

private:
    class Bar {};
};
```

What makes the third fail to compile while the first can?

Comment: Wow. Option three kills VS2015's compiler dead. Don't see the compiler crash all that often.

Comment: Anyway, constructors of `Foo`3 must provide a `Foo::Bar`, and they can't since it's private. This puts this code in an inconsistent state. Not surprised it doesn't compile, but can't cite rules. But why then does the second one compile? `Bar` will also be private, but defined ahead of the `Foo` constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, in C++, you can only reference declarations that were previously made in the translation unit. However, within a class definition, the definition of member functions are allowed to reference declarations which are made later in the class. Basically, the compiler restructures your in-class definitions so that they work as though they were written just after the class.

But this is only true of the function definitions. The *declaration* of the function (including parameter types) isn't allowed to do this. They can only reference declarations that have already been made in file order.

So you can do this:

```
class Test
{
    public:
      void Func(int x) {Inner foo;}

    private:
      class Inner {};
};
```

But not this:

```
class Test
{
    public:
      void Func(Inner x) {}

    private:
      class Inner {};
};
```

Comment: In other words, bodies have full visibility, but the method definition does not. And this makes me feel like a fool because [I read this  this morning.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079271/declaring-class-variables-after-assigning-them-values-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

First example does not expose anything about `private Bar` to the outside, while third does.

Third example is pretty much saying, that there exist some class `Foo`, which has constructor with single argument of type `Bar`. But `Bar` is unknown to the outside. Imagine calling such constructor.

```
Foo f{Foo::Bar{}};
```

Will result probably in something like `Foo::Bar` is inaccessible.

Comment: That's my thinking as well, but it doesn't explain how `Foo` version 2 gets a pass from the compiler.